# Pep boys battery check reliable?

Tags: battery

I am at Pep boys for a battery check. They attached some testing equipment to the battery (without disconnecting it from the car) and in two minutes minutes a print out came out and they said my battery  is no good.

My question is whether this type of quick testing is enough to conclude the battery is the problem,  or could the cause be the alternator or something  else.

I have attached a picture of the test results. [image: test results]

I just felt this test was not enough to jump into a conclusion about the battery.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't think this was not enough. It is one of the core services they provide, and the calculations needed are very well understood.

Comment: I suggest not going to Pep Boys for anything.

Comment: Rory, if the calculations needed are "very well understood", could you please explain them to us?

Comment: i went to pep boys only because the other places were too crowded today :)

Comment: If you get your battery tested at a place like this, make sure it's charged (charge it overnight using an external battery charger). I once had a battery that was only a year old, but was discharged dozens of times due to leaving the lights on (door sensor was broken, so it didn't beep when the door was open). Battery was dead when I got it tested; they said either it's just dead, or it's bad. The battery was the problem in the end.

Comment: If your concerned on their equipment not being fair or used properly there is a good chance another free location for a second test is near by.  (Autozone,Oreilys, sears, NAPA, Walmart, and so on)

Comment: Manny and Moe are generally reliable but Jack is usually hittin the sauce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the test saying the battery is bad should most likely be good. There are some things you need to look at in consideration of a bad battery. Things like:

- How old is the battery? If it's five years old, it's time for a new one most likely.
- Why did you go in the first place? I assume you are having some issues with the battery, otherwise you wouldn't have gone in the first place.

What they are looking at is the reserve capacity in the battery, which in the case of your battery, is about nothing. I'd suggest you should get it replaced sooner rather than later.

Comment: Paulster, seems to me you are saying in other words that this test is "most likely" reliable. You are pointing to other things that should be considered to reach a conclusion. The "reserve capacity" is low but does that necessarily mean the battery is bad (unable to recharge), or could it be the alternator, a short circuit draining the battery or some other issue in the car? I guess you are saying - yes - it could be something else. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No. I'm stating the battery is bad. There is no doubt in my mind. The test Pep Boys ran on the battery is conclusive. The voltage of the battery is good (as shown by the scale being on the high end) and in the first section by indicating 12.9vdc. The reserve capacity is how much actual power is being stored in the battery, which in this case (as shown by the second section) shows basically nothing there. The reserve capacity is shot. I was just pointing out to you if you went in with battery concerns, they do the test to show you its bad, yet you are doubting the outcome. You really shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

This is absurd. The battery needs to be replaced immediately. All the machinations & philosophy back & forth about Pep Boys being sued, & how many CCA required in a cold climate don't mean anything. If the battery is rated for 750 CCA, & you're getting 301 CCA IT MEANS it could deteriorate to 0 CCA within the next month. Will it? Maybe not. If you like being stranded, keep on driving without changing the battery & philosophizing. It should show 100% charged. If you drove it there, & the battery isn't fully charged, it means it can't be, that means it's dying. How fast will it die? Real soon. Maybe not this minute, maybe not this month, but it's not going to last a year. It might not last a month, & it might not even start the next time. GET A NEW BATTERY.

I played your game once. I was told my battery was on its way out. I doubted it, figured they were trying to sell me a new battery. It died the next week. The output from that machine they use is clear. Your battery is really, really, really bad and is really, really going to die really, really soon.

Answer (score 1):

A battery test is a simple thing, it's difficult to screw that up. As you suggest, you do need to be careful interpreting a battery test.

In your case, the 3rd section is indicating that your battery is almost fully charged, but the 1st section is indicating it no longer has the ability to produce enough current to start the car reliably. This combination can only be caused by a bad battery.

A bad alternator would have left your battery only partially charged.

Comment: "Enough current to start the car reliably" depends on how you use the car and the climate you are in. If the weather is warm, the engine is also warm most of the time (e.g. only one cold start per day) and you use the car every day, then 300A compared with the rated 750A (which should be good for sub-zero temperatures) is probably plenty. But batteries can go from "a bit weak" to "totally failed" with no warning at all, so it depends how reliable you want your car to be. I have no idea what the "state of health" test is actually measuring.

Comment: tlhIngan, are you saying that by measuring the voltage and the current of the battery under some load for a very short period of time we can confidently determine that a battery is bad? By "bad battery" I mean a battery that won't recharge properly even when everything else in the car is good (alternator good, connectors and cabling good, and there are no short circuits draining the battery).

Comment: @Marquez In my experience, whenever I've tested the battery just to eliminate it from my diagnosis, it always tested good. And whenever I've tested the battery and I had a hunch it was the cause, it always failed. Of course, the battery test must be interpreted in the context of what's going on in the car.

Answer (score 1):

Pep Boys has been sued many times for selling parts that were not needed. Mis-calibrated equipment can cause false readings. Even there starters and generators are suspect if they have a core deposit as the one you buy is not new but rebuilt. As said above replace every 5 years and if you have a multimeter the running voltage should be between 13.8-14.2 volts. The outside range would be 13.5 to 14.5. Less or more then that is a alternator/voltage regulator issue and a overcharge is as bad as a undercharge as it will lead to shorter battery life.

Answer (score -1):

Breezer wins this time. Just had PB test my battery. It was bad. Got a new one. No more problems. Some times one has to spend time stranded on a dark road at night to really get a "feel" for rather the test was correct or not. Do not take his word. Let your feet tell you that you need a new battery.